# How to use onclick on html attributes inside JSX with Typescript

Tags: typescript, reactjs

Typesript is giving the following error when attempting to use onclick on any HTML element I use.

```
ERROR in /Volumes/WorkSpace/Projects/wirecash-client/src/elements/dropdown/Dropdown.tsx
(25,45): error TS2339: Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>'.
```

My component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ClientTypes } from 'types'

interface Props {
  items: Array<ClientTypes.DropdownItem>
  onClick(item:ClientTypes.DropdownItem): () => void
}

const Dropdown = ({onClick, items}) => {
  let selectedItem = null;
  for(let i=0, j=items.length; i<j; i++) {
    if(items[i].selected) {
      selectedItem = items[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="dropdown show">
      <a className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {selectedItem.name}
      </a>

      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <button className="dropdown-item" onclick={onClick(item)}>
            Action
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dropdown
```

Answer (score 2):

The onclick attribute must be camel cased `onClick`

This works!

```
<button className="dropdown-item" onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
  Action
</button>
```